# PHP Regex to match group of Arabic Keywords

Tags: php, regex, arabic

i have this,

```
/(?<!\pL)(أحمد|محمد|حسن|محسن|على|حاتم|مصطفى)(?!\pL)/iu
```

it match just one word, maybe the first one, take a look here (https://regex101.com/r/3CEPHo/1)

how can i make it match all, and is there best practice in this? this words in the group may exceed 2000 work, is matching it with regex right?

Comment: Use global modifier '/g', so it ends up with `)(?!\pL)/gui`

Comment: Ah, for PHP specificly, you need to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: Does this require an arabic locale to be configured locally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to match all Arabic characters including spaces

For PHP

```
/\p{Arabic}/u
```

Or this (language independent):

```
/[ا-ي]/g
```